# How can I enumerate pixels in a one-pixel width numpy binary mask?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

How can I enumerate pixels in a one-pixel width numpy binary mask? Enumeration should be in one direction (clockwise or opposite). Mask could touch the edge of the image or be in the center.

I would like to use pixels numbers for the creation 1D array with pixels intensities from a raw image.

Circular mask:

[image: Circular mask]

On border mask

[image: On border mask]

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Have you tried solving this problem yourself?

Comment: I tried to fill pixels with unique numbers recursively but my machine dumped. Is there an approach with fewer resource requirements?

Comment: So you want to assign a unique value for each pixel within a binary mask? @BorysOlifirow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just start from the first pixel and then

1. remove the pixel from the image (or mark as used)
2. look in the 3x3 neighborhood for another unused pixel
3. move there and repeat from 1

If the path is exactly one pixel wide this algorithm with traverse it and at each intermediate step there will be exactly one pixel you can choose in step 2, except at the beginning when there will be two of them (one leading to CW traversal and another leading to CCW traversal).

In code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import array

src = numpy.uint8(Image.open("path.png")).copy()
h, w, _ = src.shape

x0 = y0 = None
for y in range(h):
    if x0 is not None:
        break
    for x in range(w):
        if src[y][x][0]:
            x0, y0 = x, y
            break
path = []
while True:
    src[y0][x0][0] = 0
    path.append((x0, y0))
    nx = ny = None
    for yy in (y0-1, y0, y0+1):
        for xx in (x0-1, x0, x0+1):
            if 0 <= yy < h and 0 <= xx < w and src[yy][xx][0]:
                nx, ny = xx, yy
    if nx is None: break
    x0, y0 = nx, ny
print(path)

out = array.array('B', [128]) * (w*h)
for i, (xx, yy) in enumerate(path):
    out[yy*w+xx] = i * 256 // len(path)
open("out.pgm", "wb").write(b"P5\n%i %i 255\n" % (w, h) + out.tobytes())
```

[image: Input image]
[image: Output omage]

In the second images pixel color is represents the step (the path was followed counter-clockwise)